# tensorflow rnn_decoder perform softmax on each decoder_output

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, google-cloud-ml-engine

I tried to write my own estimator model_fn() for a GCP ML Engine package. I decoded a sequence of outputs using [embedding_rnn_decoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_decoder) as shown below:

```
outputs, state = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_rnn_decoder(
    decoder_inputs = decoder_inputs,
    initial_state = curr_layer,
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(hidden_units),
    num_symbols = n_classes, 
    embedding_size = embedding_dims,
    feed_previous = False)
```

I know that outputs is "A list of the same length as decoder_inputs of 2D Tensors" but I am wondering how I can use this list to calculate the loss function for the entire sequence?

I know that if I grab outputs[0] (ie. grab only the first sequence output) then I could loss by following:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(
    outputs[0],
    n_classes)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits, labels=labels)
```

Is it appropriate to generate a loss value for each out the items in output and then pass these all to tf.reduce_mean? This feels inefficient, especially for long sequences -- are there any other ways to calculate the softmax at each step of the sequence that would be more efficient?

Comment: Is this information useful? https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq#sampled_softmax_and_output_projection

Comment: No, that does not help. My issue is not solved by sampled softmax. My issue is that I need to perform multiple iterations of softmax (on each output of the RNN). I would need to calculate the loss (or sampled softmax loss) at each step in the sequence and that is where I am not sure how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solution to my problem is to use [sequence_loss_by_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/sequence_loss_by_example)

Comment: That is in a package called "legacy". I've added a link to the non-legacy version, but note that it, too, is in contrib/ (a type of incubation).

Comment: I was using the "legacy" package to generate my outputs, so the legacy package seems like hte more appropriate metric to rely on for this question

Comment: Staying within the same package is probably a good idea. Consider moving off of legacy at some point. I suspect they don't update it with bug fixes or performance enhancements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [sequence_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss) (currently in contrib/ a type of incubation).